# Not able to become a different sudo user using ansible in GCE

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

- I have two GCE instances (say node1, node2).
- I have installed ansible in node1 and is running a script to start a service in node2.
- SSH as root is disabled in GCE instances, so I created a separate user (devops) in node1 and ran the script as devops user.
- There is no root password set in both instances, So I am able to become the root user and execute the whoami command successfully.
- But when i try same after creating a separate user it asks for "sudo: a password is required" but there is no root user password set.

My sample ansible playbook that i tried

https://gist.github.com/pavananms/a7a99a8b1f50ea3ab70e8dddbf4cb56c

I am running the above script as
**ansible-playbook test.yml**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want a password to become to the app_user, you need add this line into /etc/sudoers file:

```
app_user        ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
```

But if you see my test case here:

https://gist.github.com/sherlockholmes/63607e10457d260c5d7c61bfc1f74fad

The password is of the firt user, in my case the vagrant user. You could pass this password as an extra variable.

```
--extra-vars='ansible_become_pass=4nsible'
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. One more question can i use ssh keys instead of password to become some other user as by default the the script runner devops does not have password set so for above to work I need to set password for devops user.

Comment: Also tried adding app_user        ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL to /etc/sudoers file before becoming app_user it says "Timeout (12s) waiting for privilege escalation prompt" what could be the peoblem. My new playbook is as in the link https://gist.github.com/pavananms/a7a99a8b1f50ea3ab70e8dddbf4cb56c

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `devops` user for ansible ssh login & trying to become a sudo then add below entry to `/etc/sudoers` file on target/remote server.

```
devops ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
```

Passing any password in command as a plain text is risky for an env, to pass in ansible playbook or command always use **ansible vault**.